# Create a temporary table or not for performance with ListView

Tags: asp.net, oracle, listview

I'm relatively new to .NET and the controls it contains.  I realize that this question is really open to opinion, but would appreciate the input of those of you who've had to support .NET pages where your database record sets were in the millions of records.

I have an Oracle table that will grow to several hundred thousand rows and likely to over 5-10 million over the next few years.  Our current system that this is replacing is 6 million records.  Not massive, but enough to impact page performance.  We want to be able to display the data via an ASPX page with typical Next Page/Previous Page navigation.  The user would have the ability to search/filter the data to limit their record set, but could still potentially have two to three pages (100-300 records) of results.

It is my understanding that the ListView object in .NET retrieves all of the records in your data source's SELECT statement and then the filtering/paging controls manipulate the results at the .NET server instead of at the database (until you issue a new databind()).  This seems to be a potential performance issue in larger record sets that we are already seeing with just a few thousand records where the filter controls don't appear to filter until the entire underlying tables records are returned to .NET.  If this is an incorrect assumption or understanding, please correct me.

Given the potential growth of our system, we're concerned about performance down the road.  We're considering that we might be better off using a `SELECT ... FROM ... where rownum>1 and rownum<=50` to work through our data pagination in our databind forcing the pagination to happen on the database side and executing on every page change, so that we're only working with a few hundred records at a time on the .NET side.  Is this a false assumption regarding performance?  Is there a performance issue with .NET performing the paging on large record sets?

My final question is if we're better off doing our pagination in the database rather than .NET, would we be better off storing our initial search results in a session specific temporary table and then using that as the basis of our paginated data rather than running the above query repeatedly against the master table as we move through the records?

Thank you in advance for everyone's input.

Comment: Don't store stuff in a temp table. That is a waste of resources. I would do pagination with the rownum method.  Google "Ask Tom pagination" to see some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your input OldProgrammer.  That was my original thinking, but then I ran across [Don Burleson's post](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_temporary_tables_sql.htm) and thought maybe temp tables would speed process up and possibly be less overhead.

Comment: Okay I found two answers from [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:76812348057).  If your results takes a long time to execute, he uses a _temp_ table otherwise use a nested set of subqueries.